# Setting margin on view in RelativeLayout programmatically doesn't have any affect

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, margins

In Android, I create an ImageView in the Java code and set its layout parameters: width, height and top margin before adding it to the main layout (RelativeLayout). The width and height are applied successfully, but the margin doesn't have any affect on the image view position. The actual top margin stays 0.

How to apply the top margin to views? The code is below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initClouds();
    }

    private void initClouds() {
        addCloud(R.drawable.cloud1, R.dimen.cloud1_top_margin);
        addCloud(R.drawable.cloud2, R.dimen.cloud2_top_margin);
    }

    private void addCloud(int imageResId, int topMarginResId) {
        RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        ImageView cloud = new ImageView(this);
        int height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cloud_height);
        int width = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cloud_width);
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(width, height);
        params.topMargin = (int) getResources().getDimension(topMarginResId);
        cloud.setImageResource(imageResId);
        mainLayout.addView(cloud, params);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that `getResources().getDimension(topMarginResId)` returns not 0?

Comment: Yes, it returns non-zero value. I've logged the results and got the correct values:

    topMargin=120
    topMargin=30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting the margin for a view inside RelativeLayout you should use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams . Change your code like this ,

```
private void addCloud(int imageResId, int topMarginResId) {
        RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        ImageView cloud = new ImageView(this);
        int height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cloud_height);
        int width = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.cloud_width);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
        param.topMargin = (int) getResources().getDimension(topMarginResId);

        cloud.setImageResource(imageResId);
        mainLayout.addView(cloud, param);
    }
```

Comment: can you post your screen shot?

Comment: I tried LayoutParams from other layout: LinearLayout. But the correct RelativeLayout.LayoutParams makes a big change and does work.